# Magnitude of an Electric field as superposition of plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, fourier-transform, plane-wave

I need to show the magnitude $u(x,y,z)$ of an arbitrary electric field can be written as a superposition of infinite number of plane waves travelling along different directions.
Can someone provide with hints on how to proceed with the problem.

I think maybe we have to use the time-frequency relation i.e., Fourier transform. I have no other idea on how to proceed with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. Any (nice) complex function of $f(x,y,z)$ can be written as a linear combination of plane-wave functions $e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$ where $\vec{k}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. The reason is that these plane-wave functions form a complete basis for the vector space of all (nice) functions. The coefficient of a particular plane-wave function in this linear combination is found out by taking the inner product of the function $f$ with the plane-wave function $u_{\vec{k}}\equiv e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$. Thus, you see that the coefficient $c_{\vec{k}}$ of the wave-function $u_{\vec{k}}$ is $\int~dx~dy~dz\  e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}f(x,y,z)$. All in all, you've found that in order to express a given function as the linear combination of plane-wave functions, you have to perform the Fourier transform, i.e., $f(x,y,z)=\int \frac{d^3\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3}c_\vec{k}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$ where, as we just argued, $c_\vec{k}=\int~dx~dy~dz\  e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}f(x,y,z)$. The factor of $(2\pi)^3$ is just to ensure the correct normalisation, i.e., to ensure that the Fourier transform of a Fourier transform gives you back the original function. If you don't include the factor, you'd get back the original function multiplied by the factor of $(2\pi)^3$.